# Installed python 2.7.3 and all my libraries are on python 2.6.

Tags: python, path

I installed version 2.7.3, and whenever I type:

```
import numpy
```

I get an error message saying I don't have it installed. but when I run python 2.6, it imports it beautifully. The same happens with all my previous libraries : scipy, numpy, cv,cv2, networkx. I think it has to do with switching the python library path for the new default version. How do I do this?

Comment: Please post the complete error traceback.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the library separately for each python version. These libraries aren't shared and shouldn't be shared between different version of python.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS by the way. Whenever I run python it says its on its 2.7.3 default version, but when I install with:
    pip install networkx
it installs itself on the 2.6 version. The same goes for installing it with:
    python setup.py build
Error persists in installing in the 2.6 version. When I run python 2.7.3 which as said before is my default, and ask 'import numpy', it says 'no module found' ....

Comment: You have use pip from python 2.7 installation, and use that to install packages. Your pip are from 2.6, so it'll install package for python 2.6.

Comment: How do i use pip from python 2.7? I'm assuming that because python 2.7.3 is already set default, all I can do is "pip install numpy" or how do I specify the pip for 2.7? In the other post they suggest me to use pip-2.7 but the terminal tells me it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Python `sys.path` will hold list of path where it needs to look to import a library, in case you are confident that libraries installed in `python2.6` will work in `python2.7`, you need to update `sys.path` every time you load interpreter.

In case you are using GNU/Linux you can add export `PATH=/path/to/py2.6/library:$PATH` to ~/.bashrc.

It advised to use `pip` and install all your libraries in python2.7 .

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html

Since `python2.7` and `python2.6` are installed, carefully use them while installing libraries.

`[EDIT]`

`$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py

$ python get-pip.py`

and start using `pip-2.7` or `pip` accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS by the way. Whenever I run python it says its on its 2.7.3 default version, but when I install with: pip install networkx it installs itself on the 2.6 version. The same goes for installing it with: python setup.py build Error persists in installing in the 2.6 version. When I run python 2.7.3 which as said before is my default, and ask 'import numpy', it says 'no module found' ....

Answer (score 1):

If you download the numpy source, untar, and cd to the numpy directory, and type (as root)

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```

python 2.7 will install numpy in its own area. Same should apply for the other modules you mention.

The problem is that most installers will just look for `python`, which is linked to whatever your Ubuntu installation uses by default. In theory you could do something like

```
sudo cp -f $(which python2.7) $(which python)
```

to overwrite this link, but overwriting your system default python installation is a **very** bad idea and will almost certainly break something.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for CentOS 6, as it uses python 2.6 for the system and Yum depends on it. My workaround was to temporarily rename the `/usr/bin/python` binary to something else (e.g., `/usr/bin/orig-python`). Then I made a link to the python 2.7 installation:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

And voilà, it worked perfectly.

This works in case you have a stubborn program that won't take the settings in your `$PATH` because normally you should be able to execute the correct python if it is configured in your path.